# Reputation not given for an answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Hello,
I think I occurred in a strange situation. I have opened the stack overflow page about 15/20 minutes ago and my reputation was 1.774.

Then I had a notification of a [marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011074/jquery-uploadify-how-to-use-oncomplete/4011135#4011135) (+15 in reputation) but the reputation did not changed.

Then again I had a notify for an [upvote to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor/4072787#4072787) and the reputation raised to 1784.

It's not for the points. Just for signaling a potential bug

Regards

[image]

Comment: It's always for the points...

Comment: @Downvoter: obviously! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be explained with a glance at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4011074/timeline).

> Oct 25 '10
>   12:27  accepted  A  Lorenzo
>
> Nov 1 '10
>   08:21  unaccepted  A  Lorenzo
>   08:21  accepted  A  Lorenzo

Or, to summarize: your reputation didn't change because your final reputation didn't actually change. The author of the question unaccepted your answer and then reaccepted it over the course of 11 seconds. That's a very short window to notice the 15 point drop.

Comment: This is exactly what happened.

Comment: Good to know that SO worked the right way in this case. Anyway there should be also a better explanation of this in the reputation history page where the user see a "fake" +15. Please see the screenshot I have added to the question for details. Thanks for the clarification.